# HTTP Dynamic Streaming with video.js flash fallback

Tags: video.js

I am evaluating video.js flash fallback capabilities for live streaming.
I can stream using either RTMP or Adobe HTTP Dynamic Streaming.

Hovewer, nonne of the options seems to be supported,

here is my demo set up

```
  <video id="example_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls preload="none" width="640" height="264"
  poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png"
  data-setup="{}">
   <source src="http://mysite.com:1935/live/android.stream/manifest.f4m" type="video/mp4" />  
   <source src="rtmp://mysite.com/live" type="video/mp4" />
   <source src="http://mysite.com:1935/live/android.stream/playlist.m3u8" type='video/mp4' />
```

here is what I see in the firebug console

Specified "type" attribute of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource http://mysite.com:1935/live/android.stream/manifest.f4m failed.

Specified "type" attribute of "video/mp4" is not supported. Load of media resource rtmp://mysite.com/live failed.

Comment: Video.js touts on their homepage that the player supports live HHTP streaming (not RTMP) but there is ZERO documentation to back this up. So we wait...

Comment: New version was just released with a proper RTMP support.

Answer (score 1):

I went through the source code of the video.js (both JavaScript and ActionScript) and couldn't find any support for manifest files. 
That is a feature I would also like to see...

Comment: I couldn't find the way to play RTMP stream either :-(

Comment: @MarkoRistic - what do you mean VideoJS has upport for RTMP? I didn't think it did...

Comment: You can only play back RTMP thru the Flash Player; it's a custom protocol built by Adobe. I know this thread is old but I doubt that any new custom HTML5 video player (including JWPlayer and VideoJS) will ever support playing RTMP (other than thru Flash fallback). Streaming video over HTTP (using manifests and video chunks) is the future.

Answer (score 1):

Rtmp is now supported in video.js an example can be seen by using there already packaged file or this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Video.js</title>


  <link href="video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="video.js"></script>
  <script>
    videojs.options.flash.swf = "video-js.swf";
  </script>


</head>
<body>

<video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" controls
  preload="auto" width="640" height="264" data-setup='{ "techOrder": ["flash"] }'>
  <!-- Stream testing -->
  <source src="rtmp://rtmp.jim.stream.vmmacdn.be/vmma-jim-rtmplive-live/jim" type='rtmp/mp4'>
</video>

      <p>Source from: <a href="http://support.akamai.com/flash/">http://support.akamai.com/flash/</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps anyone currently stuck I know this has been dead for awhile.